# How to run my project while editing XML files?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I am editing an XML file and try to run my Android project (either by clicking on the "play" button in the toolbar or command-shift-F11), nothing happens. I have to switch to a java file that I'm also editing in order to run the project.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run an xml file. The way to fix this is (assuming you are using Eclipse)

> Window --> Preferences --> Run/Debug --> Launching -->

then choose "Always launch
 the previously launched application" (towards the bottom)

This may create a xml.out file. If it does you need to delete that file or you will get errors