# Running an Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

So ive downloaded the Android SDK and im going through the tutorials on the site. I have a question about Eclipse. Do i have to be on the MainActivity file to actually run the program? If i have a few files open, make changes to activity_main.xml then hit Run, it does nothing. I have to have MainActivity.java as the file open in Eclipse. Am i missing something or is that just the way it is?

Comment: Are you using the emulator, or the actual device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do i have to be on the MainActivity file to actually run the program?

No, but you do have to have a Java file as the focused file to run the app, be default anyway.

[See this answer about running from layout file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444256/how-to-run-my-project-while-editing-xml-files/15444279#15444279)

You can change the launch configurations depending on your needs. That above linked answer shows you how to get to and change the launch configuration.

Depending on how it is set up, if you try to run from a `layout` file you may get an error and it will actually add another file (`layoutFileName_out.xml`, I believe is what it calls it). If this happens, you will need to delete that file and run from a Java file or change that launch configuration.

Comment: Focused, thats the word i was trying to think of. Cheers for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to be on MainActivity or any other file. You just have to select your project to Run.

To make it easier, just right-click your project-> Run as -> Android Application

Then, you can use the Run button.